# Why is my code not able to find the input number in the file even if the input number is clearly present in the file?

Tags: python, file

This is the code to search a particular entry in a file:

```
num2find = str(input("Enter a number to find: "))

test_file = open("testfile.txt", "r")

num = "0"
flag = False
while (num != ""):
  num = test_file.readline()
  if (num == num2find):
    print("Number found.")
    flag = True
    break

if not flag:
  print("\nNumber not found.")
```

The test file is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

If I input 2, the code still outputs "Number not found."

Comment: Don't loop over files this way, *just loop over the file directly, i.e. `for line in test_file`*. In any case, **did you try printing out what each `num` is?** It should be obvious. Try `print(repr(num))`

Comment: Try changing your line to `num = test_file.readline().strip()`

Comment: @KashyapPanchal, I have added an answer to your question with some tips and improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you read a line from a text file, you are getting `"\n"` at the end of the string line, so the problem you are facing is that you are comparing `"2"` to `"2\n"` which is not the same.

You could take advantage of `with` to pen your file. This way you do not need to worry about closing the file once you are done with it. Also, you do not need to pass the `"r"` argument since it is the default mode for `open`.

You should use a for loop instead of that needless while loop. The for loop will terminate automatically when all the lines in the file have been read.

One more improvement you could make is to rename the flag `flag` to `found`, and to print the result once the file has been processed.

```py
num2find = int(input("Enter a number to find: "))

found = False # rename flag
with open("testfile.txt") as test_file: # use with to avoid missing closing the file
    for line in test_file: # use a for loop to iterate over each line in the file
        num = int(line)
        if num == num2find:
            found = True
            break

if found: # print results at the end once file was processed
    print("Number found.")
else:
    print("Number not found.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Each line in the test file contains **two** characters - the number and a newline. Since `"2"` does not equal `"2\n"`, your number is not being found. To fix this, use the `int` function to parse your lines, since it ignores whitespace (like the `\n`) character:

```py
num2find = int(input("Enter a number to find: "))

flag = False
with open("testfile.txt", "r") as test_file:
    for line in test_file:
        num = int(line)
        if num == num2find:
            print("Number found.")
            flag = True
            break

if not flag:
  print("\nNumber not found.")
```

Comment: `int` is a good idea if you're looking for numbers ; more generally, if you want to get the lines from a file still as strings but without the newlines, you can slice them out with e.g. `num = test_file.readline()[0:-1]`.

Comment: @MarkReed more reasonable would be to simply use `.strip()`... Even *more* reasonable is to stop using `readline()`

Comment: But seriously, you should change this to just iterate over `test_file`

Comment: I didn't want to make more edits than necessary, but iterating over `test_file` is **much** cleaner. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Sure, `.strip()` is fine if you want to nuke _all_ whitespace; I often want to read lines exactly as they appear in the file, just without the trailing linefeed.  At most I might use `.rstrip()` to get rid of trailing whitespace, but leading is usually significant.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and the most logical solution I could come up with after all the feedback was this:

```
num2find = int(input("Enter a number to find: "))

file_data = open("testfile.txt", "r")

found = False
for data in file_data:
  if int(data) == num2find:
    found = True

if found:
  print("\nNumber found.")
else:
  print("\nNumber not found.")

file_data.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `.rstrip()` on `num = test_file.readline()`

Try something like this:

```
num2find = str(input("Enter a number to find: "))

test_file = open("testfile.txt", "r")

file_data = test_file.readlines()
flag = False
for item in file_data:
    if num2find == item.rstrip():
        flag = True
        break

if not flag:
  print("\nNumber not found.")
else:
    print("Number found")
```

Don't use `.readline()` like that, use `readlines()` instead

Comment: I do not think that using `readlines()` is a good suggestion. What if the file has millions of lines. You will increase the space complexity since it will read all the file and put that date into memory before starting the iteration.

Comment: Right, see the answer of Gavin Uberti.

My solution is valid for files like the one above.

Comment: **don't sue `readlines`**  Use `for item in test_file`